# Unable to reopen Tilda with keyboard shortcut

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, tilda

I have been using tilda for many years and just installed it on a new pc running ubuntu 21.10.

Tilda closes when the shortcut is pressed but once tilda is hidden, it won't reopen. I can see that it hasn't crashed as the process is still running. I tried a few different shortcuts in case there is some shortcut conflict but nothing works and the shortcut clearly works since tilda responds to it when it is expanded.

Would anyone know of a solution? Could this be Wayland related?

Alternatively, a command to reopen the collapsed window so I can create a shortcut for it manually would work. The only commands I found open another instance of tilda rather than reopening the existing one...

I'm happy to try alternatives as well. however, it seems that Yakake is a Qt app and the gnome terminal drop down extensions is no longer maintained... I'm also looking at guake now just in case...

Comment: apologies for the typo, it was meant to be 21.10 :-) I'll correct this now

Comment: I can confirm the same behaviour on 22.04

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is a Wayland issue. Installing Ubuntu 21.10, and even upgrading to 21.10, moves you to Wayland.

From the [Tilda page on hithub](https://github.com/lanoxx/tilda)

> Tilda currently works only on Xorg-based desktops. ... Tilda currently does not support Wayland and will not work on such desktops. As a result it will fail to start.

So indeed, Tilda does not appear to support other mechanisms to make it work, such as having a command line option to display or hide it.

- To continue using Tilda, your only option will be to move to an Xorg session, which continues to be fully supported on an Ubuntu desktop. Log out, and on the login screen, before entering your password to log back in, click the cog icon and select Ubuntu on Xorg there.
- Alternatively, there are Gnome Shell extensions that implement a drop down terminal such as [ddterm by amezin](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3780/ddterm/). The extension  [quake-mode by repsac-by](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1411/quake-mode/) allows to turn any application in drop-down mode, so this could be used for any terminal emulator.

Comment: ok, thanks for that, I'll check these extensions. In the meantime, I played around with Guake and it's not too bad. There is a similar issue with the shortcut but at least it has a command to make it appear to I created a separate shortcut for it (https://github.com/Guake/guake/issues/1640)

Comment: Yes, I wonder why Tilda does not do that, but perhaps there are more fundamental reasons why that may not work for Tilda.

Comment: for info, I have now settled on the gnoe extension ddterm which works quite nicely: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3780/ddterm/